# Access generic type's properties by position

Tags: c#, generics

I need to access Generic type's properties using the position of property or any other similar way.

Example:

```
class model
{
    int intValue;
    string stringValue;

    public model(int a,string b){
    this.intValue = a;
    this.stringValue= b;
    }
}



public class baseClass<T>
{   
    public string value;

    public void process(T param)
    {
      value =  param.Getproperty[0].ToString();
    }

}

public class derivedClass : baseClass<model>
{
     Console.WriteLine("Converted value:" +process(new model(1,"test")));
    //Do something
}
```

My base class is actually a Generic library which performs some simple Common tasks.

Comment: "Added in runtime"? What does this mean?

Comment: Also, are you looking for [Type.GetProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i think they are confusing runtime and compile time

Comment: Example usage of the generic base class does not really tell us much on why you need this kind of approach, but I would assume using interfaces would be a good starting point.

Comment: I have Updated my question.please check now

Comment: I think he is trying to get the property value of some object(from the base class) whose model class will be supplied in derived class.

Comment: @Asker Yes and that alone tells me he is more of interested in an interface instead of a generic type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a common interface, the current interface is set to Object so anything not a member of Object can't be accessed, this is done with the [where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) keyword

this can be done explicitly with an actual interface

```
public interface IIndexedProperty
{
    object Getproperty(int index);
}

public class model:IIndexedProperty
{
    int intValue;
    string stringValue;
    public object Getproperty(int index)
    {
        //select property by index
    }
}

public class baseClass<T>
    where T:IIndexedProperty
{   
    public T item;
    item.Getproperty(0); // access intValue
    item.Getproperty(1); // access stringValue
}
```

another option would be to use model as your interface

```
public class model
{
    int intValue;
    string stringValue;
}

public void baseClass<T>
    where T:model
{   
    public T item;

    item.intValue; // access intValue
    item.stringValue; // access stringValue
}
```

the final option would be reflection

```
typeof(T).GetProperties();
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest another approach?

## If you always have 2 propeteries

```
interface TwoProperties {
  object GetProperty1();
  object GetProperty2();
}

class Model : TwoProperties {
  int intValue;
  stringStringValue;

  public override object GetProperty1() {
    return intValue;
  }

  public override object GetProperty2() {
    return stringValue;
  }
}
```

And then use `someModel.GetProperty1()` for example.

## If you have an unknown number of properties:

```
interface SomeProperties {
  object[] GetProperties();
}

class Model : SomeProperties {
  int intValue;
  stringStringValue;

  public override object[] GetProperties() {
    return new object[] { intValue, stringValue };
  }
}
```

And then use `someModel.GetProperties()[0]`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a [property indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6x16t2tx.aspx):

Sample code:

```
public class TestIndexer
{
    public string x;
    public int y;
    public object this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    return y;
                case 2:
                    return x;
                default:
                    return "";
                // return the property you want based on index i
            }
        }
    }
}

TestIndexer t = new TestIndexer();
t.y = 22;
object indexValue = t[1]; //22
```

Comment: they still wont be able to access the indexer unless they type the generic with a where clause